# A "team" has or have an assigned task?

Tags: grammar

I usually use " My team has this task to do" , but I was wondering if I am misusing has, because "People are" and the team is people.

Comment: Don’t you mean the team are people??  ;-)

Comment: US or UK?  There may be different answers, depending.  Here in the US I would say, "My team has...".

Comment: Yes, generally "team" is treated as singular (ie, an entity) in US English, but is plural (ie, a group of people) in UK English, so knowing which side of the pond you're on is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[People](https://www.lexico.com/definition/people)* is a plural noun. [*Team*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/team) can be treated as singular or plural.

So "My team *has* this task to do" is perfectly OK and, like you, I prefer it to "My team *have* this task to do."

Yes, "people *are*". And "people *have* this task to do."